# PHP: foreach array multidimensional with response in unordered HTML list

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[code] => 20171122_7_1_1_109_d28df45a4cf941ab82052d976ac97905_
[count] => 2
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [code] => 1b326e_2332105365_0_0_2_1_0_1_2332105381_0_0-0-0.20171122_7_1_1_109_d28df45a4cf941ab82052d976ac97905_
                [destination_code] => 20dc9
                [hotel_code] => 1b326e
                [additional_info] => 
                [checkin] => 2017-11-22
                [checkout] => 2017-11-29
                [price] => 853.47
                [currency] => EUR
                [pay_at_hotel] => 
                [hotel_price] => 
                [hotel_currency] => 
                [meal_type] => RO
                [nonrefundable] => 
                [view] => 
                [rooms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [pax] => Array
                                    (
                                        [children_ages] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [adult_quantity] => 1
                                    )

                                [room_category] => Standard
                                [room_description] => King
                                [nightly_prices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [2017-11-22] => 121.92
                                        [2017-11-23] => 121.92
                                        [2017-11-24] => 121.92
                                        [2017-11-25] => 121.92
                                        [2017-11-26] => 121.92
                                        [2017-11-27] => 121.92
                                        [2017-11-28] => 121.95
                                    )

                                [room_type] => SB
                            )

                    )

                [supports_cancellation] => 1
                [minimum_selling_price] => 
                [offer] => 1
                [policies] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Through a simple foreach, I can print the data of [room_category,[room_description], but I can not print, in an unordered HTML list, dates and prices of [nightly_prices], of the type:

- 2017-11-22: 121.92
- 2017-11-23: 121.92
- 2017-11-24: 121.92

etc....

The code I use is as follows:

```
$data2 = json_decode($result2, true);
foreach($data2['results'] as $key=>$val){ 
echo $val['rooms'][0]['nightly_prices']
}
```

but running only shows me Array.

Comment: you need to foreach $val['rooms'][0]['nightly_prices']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array so you have to loop on it to get each value :

```
$data2 = json_decode($result2, true);
 foreach($data2['results'] as $key=>$val){ 
   foreach($val['rooms'][0]['nightly_prices'] as $k => $v){
      echo $k.' '.$v;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `echo` for arrays, you'll need to use `print_r` instead:

```
print_r($val['rooms'][0]['nightly_prices']);
```